# Does umbraco 6.1.4 supports PURE MVC implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Currently I am using umbraco 4.7.1 and planning to upgrade to version 6. But I will only go ahead it it allows PURE MVC approach. Here what I mean is I **DON'T** want to use any of ASP.NET like master page for templates. Everything should be in MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a site in Umbraco 6 using just MVC including layout pages and all the other MVC bits, i.e. not master pages.

The administration section of Umbraco isn't MVC though, but that just works as usual. I havn't tried to add any MVC admin sections myself yet.

I'm building a pure MVC site in Umbraco 6, it's my first MVC site but it's all pretty much like the MVC book says.

When I create views etc. in Visual Studio, sub folders don't work well in the Umbraco admin section, it doesn't do sub folders very well.  Also you have to set up your own version of the application start, which is no real problem but apart from that it's all sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I use Umbraco 6.1.3 and master pages are there. You can use old ASP.NET approach or MVC approach.

Comment: Can i dump master pages and use the Layout pages.

Comment: I manage all webs (with master pages, scripts, css, scripting files etc.) from umbraco administration. When I create my last web (Umbraco 6.1.3), I wrote everything manualy in administration GUI, but I use same structure as in old umbraco. So I think, that you can dump master and layout pages and use it.